# FQL: Unexpected end of query

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to retrieve events that the user logged in has been invited to. While I was testing some stuff, I got stuck in this error while trying this FQL query:

```
public static List<GraphLocation> getEvents(Session session, Map<String, Object> queryParams){
    limpar();

    queryStringBuilder.append("SELECT eid, all_members_count, attending_count, declined_count, description, end_time, version, " +
                                     "name, location, pic, privacy, start_time, ticket_uri, timezone, unsure_count, venue " +
                              "FROM event");

    if(queryParams != null && !queryParams.isEmpty()){
        whereClause.append(" WHERE ");

        if(!queryParams.containsKey("dataInicio")){
            whereClause.append("start_time = " + formatter.format((Date) queryParams.get("dataInicio")));
        }
    }

    queryStringBuilder.append(whereClause.toString());

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", queryStringBuilder.toString());

    Request request = new Request(session, "/fql",  params, HttpMethod.GET, 
            new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            });

    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

    return null;
}
private static void limpar(){
    queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    whereClause = new StringBuilder();
}
```

and here is the link to the image error on imageshack: http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/6848/erroew.png

If someone can tell me why is that issue happening I will be very happy, anyway, I will be even more happy if someone can also explain me how to grab events that a specific user is invited to.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're referring to an error, but the error is not included in the question as far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry sir, I forgotten, btw I just added an link to the error image, and thanks for spend your time on helping people like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FQL query needs a WHERE statement, this is the cause of "Unexpected end of query" exception.

The Query you are looking for is this one

```
SELECT eid, all_members_count, attending_count, declined_count, description, end_time, version, name, location, pic, privacy, start_time, ticket_uri, timezone, unsure_count, venue 
                FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = XXXXXXX ) 
                ORDER BY start_time asc
```

Replace XXXXXXX with the facebook user id.

In order to test FQL queries before integrating them into your code you can use Facebook Graph API Explorer, like [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20eid%2C%20all_members_count%2C%20attending_count%2C%20declined_count%2C%20description%2C%20end_time%2C%20version%2C%20name%2C%20location%2C%20pic%2C%20privacy%2C%20start_time%2C%20ticket_uri%2C%20timezone%2C%20unsure_count%2C%20venue%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20IN%20%28%20SELECT%20eid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20XXXXXXXXX%20%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20start_time%20asc).

Note: don't forget to add "user_events" permission to your facebook app.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help, and thanks again for the quick reply.